# Referencing "this" from within a javascript callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Something has always bothered me about the way I do object-oriented coding in Javascript. When there's a callback, I frequently want to reference the object which originally called the function, which leads me to do something like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(obj, callback) {
    var me = this; // ugh
    obj.loadSomething(function(err, result) {
        me.data = result; // ugh
        callback(null, me);
    });
}
```

First off, creating the additional variable alway seemed... excessive to me. Furthermore, I have to wonder if it might end up causing problems (circular references? un-GCd objects?) by passing the "me" variable back to the callback.

Is there a better way to go about this? Is this approach evil?

Comment: `this` is not a variable. `this` cannot be closed over. The approach is fine.

Comment: The FUD about "evil" and "excessive" bothers me. It's okay to not like the boilerplate but why invent imaginary problems with it? You need to retain a reference to the same enclosing data no matter what approach you use, because the inner function doesn't change. Whether you'll only keep a reference to the least data necessary is something that the interpreter should worry about.

Comment: @millimoose Well said - I failed to come up with a way to summarize that last line. (And I still run into "evil" - well not "evil", but truly awful in a very objective way - code that uses `new Function("..")` to "avoid issues".)

Comment: @millimoose perhaps you misunderstood. I was uncertain that this was the *correct* boilerplate to begin with. It was a practice I had stolen from somewhere along the line and never confirmed that it was, indeed, a *good* practice... thus the FUD.

Comment: @pst Hell, if we define "evil" as "makes maintaining more difficult", it's probably *less* evil to bind `this` to a meaningful name instead of having the same "variable" refer to a bunch of different objects over the course of a single logical function. (Where, given the nature of JS code, a "logical function" can contain quite a few other tiny ones, like `jQuery.each()` callbacks, event handlers, or continuations.)

Comment: @ZaneClaes While there's a way to get rid of the boilerplate (the one in my answer), I don't think you always should. That said, your case, when `loadSomething` doesn't rebind the callback's `this` to anything meaningful, is probably a good use for binding though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is for:

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(obj, callback) {
    obj.loadSomething((function(err, result) {
        this.data = result;
        callback(null, this);
    }).bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Might want to change `me` to `this`

Comment: +1 for the good answer, accepted answer for the documentation link.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, what you are doing is the accepted pattern for this kind of thing, and doesn't cause any issues.  A lot of people use either "self" or "that" as the stored reference - "self" can be more intuitive if you come from a python background.

Comment: I like `self`. However there *is* also `window.self` .. although I have never run into confusion on the issue.

Comment: And self can be confused sometimes with [window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self)

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior for JavaScript. The context for `this` has changed for the `loadSomething` object, and the reason for having the callback is to capture closure references like your `me` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind this to the scope of the inner function

```
MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(obj, callback) {
    obj.loadSomething(function(err, result) {
        this.data = result;
        callback(null, this);
    }.bind( this ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common way I have seen to handle it, I usually use var self = this;, but its just a name.  Even though it is an extra variable, considering the javascript overhead and the fact that it doesn't duplicate the object, it really isn't going to impact performance.